# 'Variable' assignments in Python

Tags: python, pickle

In Python I want to assign values to certain variables by putting them first in a list and assigning them values by indexing. For example:

I want to assign x = 1, y = 2, z = 3.

Rather than coding it one by one, I want to assign the variables as follows:

```
list_variables = [x, y, z]

list_values = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(0, 3):

 list_variables[i] = list_values[i]
```

However it does not work. This type of assigning would really make my life easier because I am having hard time loading saved data to my variables by the pickle.load method. Thank you.

Comment: Can you just do `x, y, z = [1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: `x, y, z = 1, 2, 3`

Comment: There are no variable references in Python. `list_variables` contains the values of the variables. Assigning just updates the list, not the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to put variable names on LHS and the value list on RHS

```py
x,y,x = value_list
```

this will automatically spread the values to the variables

Comment: Thank you very much Rohit Patil. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: My pleasure :) @atakulaksizoglu